# Possible to remove center middle red "youtube play" button form iframe embedded video?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, youtube-api

I want to remove the youtube player and center middle youtube red play button.

I want to control play pause by custom button.

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xyz?enablejsapi=1&html5=1&rel=0&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

EDIT

have already used the above parameters but this does not hide the center play button. is it possible to change that button?

need to remove this from the iframe: 
[image]

Comment: Add some code please

Comment: Add the link so that we can work on it.

Comment: Please take a tour of the help centre to see how to ask a good question and what sorts of question are on topic for this site.  In it's current form this is not on topic and is not a good question

Comment: Added some code also wanted to disable youtube red button

Comment: At least there is no official, documented way, otherwise it would be [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters).

Answer (score 1):

please find following parameters which will be useful.

```
showinfo=0,video will not  display the title on video frame. 
controls=0,hides the bottom bar
autohide=1,hides the controls
```

please use following link for further details

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters

Comment: have already used these but this does not hide the center play button. is it possible to change that button?

'http://codepen.io/Shahadat321/pen/KNbzJR'